# finding the common values that exist in two vector

Tags: r, vector

The following code doesn't give me the right answer. Do you know why?

Consider the vector c(25,29,20,0,6,29,15,17,22,2,9,6,17,26,24,5,3,26,6,28,25,7,18,21,6,14,20,8,15,3). 
Find the sum of values in the vector above that are also in this vector: c(0, 5, 25, 1, 2, 18, 17, 28, 18, 29, 16, 1, 8, 6, 1).

```
v<- c(25,29,20,0,6,29,15,17,22,2,9,6,17,26,24,5,3,26,6,28,25,7,18,21,6,14,20,8,15,3)
v2<-c(0, 5, 25, 1, 2, 18, 17, 28, 18, 29, 16, 1, 8, 6, 1)
v21<-intersect(v2,v)
sum(v21)
```

Also how can I use `%in%` for solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use `%in%` for this:

```
sum(v[v %in% v2])
# [1] 227
```

The reason your solution with `intersect` didn't work is that it removes duplicate values in `v`. For instance, with `v = c(2, 2, 3)` and `v2 = c(2, 4)`, `intersect(v, v2)` is equal to `c(2)`, not `c(2, 2)`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It was great. Yeah, apparently we shouldn't make use of intersect as it omits the repetition.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
sum(v2[match(v, v2, nomatch = 0)])
# [1] 227
```

From the R docs:

```
%in% is currently defined as 
"%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0
```

So using `match` directly may be a little faster (didn't test it for speed tough).

Comment: Sounds like I cannot select both of you and Josibler's answer. But your answer is correct too.

Comment: No problem, he was faster than me =)

Comment: @Fernando In cases like this, you should edit your original answer and undelete it -- people can (and usually do) retract downvotes after such an edit.  Such editing reduces your number of deleted answers.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Thanks for the tip, didn't tough of that.

Comment: @Fernando You're welcome.  It's important because too many deleted answers gets you an answer ban.  Us users don't know the thresholds of course, but it can happen.  In addition (and less importantly), 10K users can see the deleted answer.